# How to run join on pandas crosstab

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, crosstab

I am trying to create a Pandas crosstab, but I then want to run a join and it won't let me since I think it's a special type of DataFrame. See below for an example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["Alice", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob","Bob","Bob","Charlie"], 'B': ["X","X","Y","X","Y","Z","Z"]})

z = pd.crosstab(df['A'],df['B'])
z.index.name="ID"
z.reset_index(inplace=True)

zz = pd.DataFrame({"ID":["Alice","Daniel","Bob","Charlie"})
zz.join(z,on="DT_ID")
```

And then I get the following error message:

`ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat`

However, if I check the dtypes, they are objects in both ID columns. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3):

`join` is for the `index` , you are looking for the `merge`

```
df=zz.merge(z.reset_index(),on="ID")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use merge.

```
#inner join
pd.merge(z,zz,on='ID')

    ID      X   Y   Z
0   Alice   2   1   0
1   Bob     1   1   1
2   Charlie 0   0   1

#right join
pd.merge(z,zz,on='ID',how='right')
    ID      X   Y   Z
0   Alice   2.0 1.0 0.0
1   Bob     1.0 1.0 1.0
2   Charlie 0.0 0.0 1.0
3   Daniel  NaN NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

It can occur in **two scenarios**
**1.** using the join method: you are probably joining DataFrames on labels and not on indices
**2.** using the merge method: you are probably joining DataFrames on two columns that are not of the same type.

**You are trying to join on labels and not on indices using the join method**

```
data_x.join(data_y, on='key')
```

**In the first scenario, you can edit your code to join the index. In the following code, I set the index on the columns I want to join.**

```
data_x.set_index('key').join(data_y.set_index('key'))
```

**But what might even be more simple, is replacing the join method with the merge method.**

```
data_x.merge(data_y)
```

**You are joining on columns of different types using the merge method**

```
data_x.merge(data_y, on='key')
```

**In this second scenario, you can simply change the column type of one of the columns — or both. A convenient way is through the astype method.**

```
data_x.key.astype(int)
data_y.key.astype(int)
data_x.merge(data_y, on='key')
```